# Copy values (mapped_type) from map to vector given a mapping from keys to indices

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl, c++14

Suppose we have a function `key_to_index` that maps keys of a map to indices of a vector. For an example, let's just make it trivial:

```
std::map<int, int> source = {{1,55}, {4, 20}, {6, 25}};
std::vector<int> target;

int key_to_index(int key) {return key;}
```

What would be a version of the following loop that uses STL algorithms?

```
for (const auto &el: source) {
    int index = key_to_index(el.first);
    if (index > (int)target.size() - 1) target.resize(index + 1);
    target[index] = el.second;
}
```

Comment: Is your `key_to_index()` function really supposed to return the `key`and not the `index`?

Comment: @Galik OP did say that he made it trivial identity function for demontration purposes. Actual implementation should not matter.

Comment: You can wrap the thing into `std::transform` and use a lambda, but other than that I'd say leave it as it is.

Comment: @DeiDei Could you please show that?

Answer (score 3):

@Edgar answer is good, however, I do not like second map creation. Assuming that `key_to_index` is reasonably fast, it is better to just run it twice more than create map with converted indices.

Obvious optimization for your code (unless `key_to_index` is too complex) is to avoid more than one resizing. Then apply `std::for_each` to original map

```
auto max = std::max_element(source.cbegin(), source.cend(), [](auto& lhs, auto& rhs) {
    return key_to_index(lhs.first) < key_to_index(rhs.first); });
target.resize(key_to_index(max->first) + 1);

std::for_each(source.cbegin(), source.cend(), [&target](const auto& e) {
    target[key_to_index(e.first)] = e.second; });
```

Comment: "I do not like second map creation". Yeah, I don't like it too. Just posted the first version which came to my mind. Anyway, +1 :)

Comment: Nice! This really looks as it may be faster than the original version. It also avoids a conditional inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can create a new *map* storing the same values with transformed keys:

```
std::map<int, int> transformed;

std::transform(std::cbegin(source), std::cend(source),
        std::inserter(transformed, transformed.end()),
        [](const auto& e) {
            return std::make_pair(key_to_index(e.first), e.second);
        }
);
```

And then fill the target:

```
std::vector<int> target;
target.resize(transformed.rbegin()->first + 1);

std::for_each(std::cbegin(transformed), std::cend(transformed),
        [&target](const auto& e) {
            target[e.first] = e.second;
        }
);
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/XvWoMH0T3NZe6vyE)

Anyway I believe that the initial version is better. STL does not always make your code more efficient or even more readable.

Comment: I hoped it would become shorter than the original code... and I definitely do not expect the version using STL to be less efficient than the original.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning sometimes it is better to avoid STL :)

Comment: @EdgarRokyan Blasphemous comment! Thumbs up!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an output iterator, very similar to `std::insert_iterator`, with the value type of `std::pair<int,int>` and `operator=` that mutates your array. Then your function can be written as `std::transform`.

Comment: Nice idea, though I would not work so hard to re-write four lines of code.